# Boolean Modifier Union produces non manifold edges

Tags: modeling

I'm working on a sculpted model, that will be 3d printed...
the problem is, I had 4 objects (the head, the two eyes, the hair) and merged them with the boolean modifier Union... but if I check for non-manifold edges, it shows, that exactly those edges between the former seperate objects are now non-manifold.
How can I fix this in a fast way? because I need this model finished today...

[image: non-manifold edges]

Comment: Try to remove doubles in those areas and increase merge distance.

Comment: What do you mean with merge distance? Where should change those? And is there an automatic process to remove doubles? Sorry, I'm a noob

Comment: Right after you executed remove doubles, hit F6 button, or you will see the operator panel in the bottom left of your screen.

Comment: That may not solve your problem, because it's very hard to see what's going on in your model.

Comment: Suggestion. See tutorials on video sites on the preparation of models for 3d printing. Try simple examples of Boolean union to increase your understanding. There are many simple union examples where Boolean might not be the full solution to a specific need.  Extra work may be needed.  Boolean union does not always produce a single solid closed volume.